# How do I retrieve the version of an Assembly in C#?

Tags: .net, assemblies

I have a reference to a type, for which I would like to retrieve the version number of the Assembly in which it is located.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use,

```
x.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version
```

Comment: If you want to access the currently executing assembly use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.